# How do you complete the following Regex

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex expression that will accept the following: The capital letter A followed by any number of digits.  This might also be a decimal number. All of these are valid: A1, A500, A543.987

This is NOT OK to accept: Apple, AE100

Currently I have `[A]\w.[0-9]*` but it accepts `App` and `AE100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest "A\d+(\.\d+)?". \d represents all digits, the + is one or more characters and the (\.\d+)? is a . followed by one or more digits. But the ? specifies it's optional.

Comment: Works great.  Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 6):

You may use the following regex if the entire string should match:

```
^A[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Or, to match these strings as whole words:

```
\bA[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKw5ax/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string / `\b` - a word boundary
- `A` - an `A`
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and then 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string  /  `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Wow you were quick. Works well. Thank you